# Servlet mapping refers to a servlet that is not defined

Tags: maven, jsf, servlets

I'm building a web project and have the following code in my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>-1</load-on-startup>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <async-supported>false</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In eclipse markers window I see following error twice: `The servlet mapping "Faces Servlet" refers to a servlet that is not defined`. Well, in my opinion it is defined right there. When I delete servlet-mapping nodes, error disappears, but the project is useless. I've tried to re-validate project and web.xml file, refresh dependencies from maven. I haven't succeeded in finding anything relevant in google search. Also, I used very similar web.xml file in another project(not maven) and there it worked fine.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: What happend if you define a single mapping instead of two? What happens if you ignore the eclipse error and deploy the app?

Comment: When I package the war with `mvn war:war` I get the message that web.xml is ignored(http://pastebin.com/g2SFEiz9). When I remove one of the mappings - one of the errors goes with it.

Comment: Check your deployment.  Which container? Check the log to see if it contains more errors etc...

Comment: I ran into this issue myself and solved it... It's weird, but if you have a **context-param** with `<param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>`, I suggest removing it, then re-building or cleaning the project, then add it back in. It worked for me.

Comment: @Sometowngeek, I'm sorry I can't confirm that (I switched jobs twice since than) but I think question will benefit if you'll post this comment as an answer.